# Intellij IDEA Error: Could not find or load main class org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher in Scala Project

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

I am facing the following error when I click Run from simple Hello World program of Scala. I am unable to find any solution as I am beginner in the Java field.

I am currently using IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.3 which I am trying to integrate with Scala but to no avail.I am following this tutorial to run the Scala Program and Install all the required softwares and libraries as mentioned in this link.

https://www.guru99.com/scala-tutorial.html

[Screenshot - Intellij IDEA Error for Scala Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC8Sb.png)

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe" -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"\" -Dpreload.project.path=D:/Scala-Projects -Dpreload.config.path=C:/Users/Khalid/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2/options -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Daether.connector.resumeDownloads=false -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=-2427656205608767245 -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2021.2 -Didea.home.path=D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win -Didea.config.path=C:/Users/Khalid/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2 -Didea.plugins.path=C:/Users/Khalid/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2/plugins -Djps.log.dir=C:/Users/Khalid/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2/log/build-log -Djps.fallback.jdk.home=D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/jbr -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=11.0.12 -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:/Users/Khalid/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2/compile-server/helloworld_14920d90/_temp_ -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.js=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"C:\Users\Khalid\AppData\Local\Temp\kotlin-idea-3911355212386532999-is-running\" -Dtmh.instrument.annotations=true -Dtmh.generate.line.numbers=true -Dcompile.parallel.max.threads=4 -Dcompile.parallel=true -Dscala.compile.server.socket.connect.timeout.milliseconds=10000 -Dscala.compiler.indices.rebuild=true -classpath "D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144/lib/tools.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/lib/annotations.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/lib/slf4j.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/lib/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/lib/jps-model.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/plugins/java/lib/javac2.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/lib/forms_rt.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-file-1.3.3.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/lib/util.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/lib/protobuf-java-3.15.8.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/lib/platform-api.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/lib/jna-platform.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/plugins/java/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/plugins/java/lib/jps-javac-extension-1.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders-6.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/lib/jna.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/lib/idea_rt.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/lib/3rd-party.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-connector-basic-1.3.3.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-http-1.3.3.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-plugin.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/plugins/IntelliLang/lib/java-langInjection-jps.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-common.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-common.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-constants-rt.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/java-guiForms-jps.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/plugins/gradle-java/lib/gradle-jps.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-jps-common.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-common.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/plugins/space/lib/space-java-jps.jar;D:/Softwares/ideaIC-2021.2.3.win/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps.jar;C:/Users/Khalid/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2/plugins/Scala/lib/scala-library.jar;C:/Users/Khalid/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2/plugins/Scala/lib/compiler-shared.jar;C:/Users/Khalid/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2/plugins/Scala/lib/jps/nailgun.jar;C:/Users/Khalid/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2/plugins/Scala/lib/jps/compiler-jps.jar;C:/Users/Khalid/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2/plugins/Scala/lib/jps/sbt-interface.jar;C:/Users/Khalid/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2/plugins/Scala/lib/jps/incremental-compiler.jar;C:/Users/Khalid/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2/plugins/Scala/lib/jps/scala-parallel-collections.jar;C:/Users/Khalid/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2/plugins/Scala/lib/spray-json_2.13-1.3.5.jar;C:/Users/Khalid/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2/plugins/Scala/lib/scala-compiler-indices-protocol_2.12-0.1.1.jar org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 57901 33b87547-d627-4a07-bd5f-0b53060f32c9 C:/Users/Khalid/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2/compile-server
Error: Could not find or load main class org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are correctly specified the **main** class in Run configuration dialog:

[image]

You can open it from the main toolbar:
[image]

Comment: I checked it in the Run/Debug Configurations Window, its coming same as 'hello' in the field.

Comment: Can you provide a sample project to check?

Comment: You want whole project folder? This give error in somehting like launcher of Intelij software which is not found by this command org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher.
Note: I didnt install the Intellij IDEA software from its Installer file, I download the zip version and using it directly from folder in the bin directory and run it from idea64.exe. This could be the reason behind it??